# PieDataSet cannot be applied to String in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

i want make PieChart with library [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) from github and i follow instruction on google or youtube, but i'm stuck in this code

```
private void addData(){

    ArrayList<Entry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    for (int i = 0; i < yData.length; i++)
        yVals1.add(new Entry(yData[i], i));

    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < xData.length; i++)
        xVals.add(xData[i]);

    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yVals1, "Market Share");
    dataSet.setSliceSpace(3);
    dataSet.setSelectionShift(5);

}
```

in

> PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yVals1, "Market Share");

I got warn, `PieDataSet Cannot Applied to String`. I don't know whats wrong because in tutorial is same with me

Comment: Your tutorial could be old and you should seek the official documentation

Comment: im confused when saw documentation

Comment: Your only option is to pass a list of `PieEntry` and a String variable. https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/PieDataSet.java#L28 ... If that is failing, then you are not using the latest version of this library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for pie chart with MPCharts, I've used this snippet

```
 protected PieData generatePieData() {

    int count = 10;

    ArrayList<PieEntry> entries1 = new ArrayList<PieEntry>();

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        entries1.add(new PieEntry( (float) salary[i], months[i]));
    }

    PieDataSet ds1 = new PieDataSet(entries1, "Monthly Salary 2017");
    ds1.setColors(ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS);
    ds1.setSliceSpace(2f);
    ds1.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    ds1.setValueTextSize(10f);
    ds1.setSliceSpace(5f);


    return new PieData(ds1);
}
```

where salary, and months are array

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the ArrayList as PieEntry?

```
ArrayList<PieEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<PieEntry>();
```

EDIT:

I think this is what you might need?;

```
        ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < xData.length; i++){
            xVals.add(xData[i]);
        }

        ArrayList<PieEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<PieEntry>();
        for (int i = 0; i < yData.length; i++){
            yVals1.add(new Entry(yData[i], xData[i]));
        }
```

Comment: Well, `PieEntry extends Entry`... but maybe

Comment: it's done and i got new same issue in `PieData data = new PieData(xVals, dataSet);`

Comment: Hmm. Is the data in xData stored as String?

Comment: @MegiFernanda `PieData` only accepts a single parameter... https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/PieData.java#L24

Comment: so how to i can set string in piechart

Comment: @MegiFernanda I've edited my answer to help. Your PieEntry values and String Values get added at the same time, as long as the title and value are in the same position within the two arrays.